Column content overflowing the column
I am using React and Bootstrap.
I have defined a container, a row, and columns.
When the screen is shrunk, the page is responsive in that the columns shrink or expand relative to the page.
However, the column content overflows out of the column itself.
<Row>
    <Col className="turtle" xs={12} md={6} lg={6} xl={6} xxl={6}>
      <h1>testttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</h1>
    </Col>
    
    <Col className="burtle" xs={12} md={6} lg={6} xl={6} xxl={6}>
      <p>im col 2</p>
    </Col>
</Row>

Image Output:
Result of column overflow
Any help on how to fix this and to keep column content from overflowing would be much appreciated.

see Word break

Adding below CSS should solve your problem-
.turtle {
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

